# How do I combine rows were of unique values across columns of character strings nested within two groups in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning, data-wrangling, imputation

This is a bit convoluted; I have a dataframe where there are patients with clinic visits and for each clinic visit there are medications with one medication per column. In some occassions, there are patients with multiple clinic visits on a single day, and they have different medications - there may be more, less, or the same number of medications recored - recorded for each visit. When this happens, I want to combine the rows into a single row that has only unique medications.  Below, the first dataframe is an example of something similar to what I have, the second is the desired output.

EDIT: If a resulting row has more than the existing number of columns, I want to add another column to make room. The number of unique drugs will be summed across the rows, so I only want to combine unique drugs.

Any solutions/guidance would be really appreciated.

```
    patient_id <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)
    dates <- c("2023-01-01", "2023-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-02")
    drug_1 <- c("paracetamol", NA, "aspirin", NA, NA,NA, NA, NA)
    drug_2 <- c("ibuprofen", "codine", NA, "paracetamol", NA, "asprin", NA, NA)
    drug_3 <- c("aspirin", "cough syrup", NA, NA, "ibuprofen", NA, NA, NA)
    drug_4 <- c(NA, "cocodamol", "ibuprofen", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
    drug_5 <- c(NA, "aspirin", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
    
    patients_data <- data.frame(patient_id,dates, drug_1, drug_2, drug_3, drug_4, drug_5);patients_data

patient_id      dates      drug_1      drug_2      drug_3    drug_4  drug_5
1          1 2023-01-01 paracetamol   ibuprofen     aspirin      <NA>    <NA>
2          1 2023-01-01        <NA>      codine cough syrup cocodamol aspirin
3          2 2022-01-01     aspirin        <NA>        <NA> ibuprofen    <NA>
4          2 2022-01-01        <NA> paracetamol        <NA>      <NA>    <NA>
5          3 2019-01-01        <NA>        <NA>   ibuprofen      <NA>    <NA>
6          3 2019-01-02        <NA>      asprin        <NA>      <NA>    <NA>
7          4 2019-01-02        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>      <NA>    <NA>
8          4 2019-01-02        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>      <NA>    <NA>
    
    patient_id <- c(1, 2,3,3,4)
    dates <- c("2023-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-02")
    drug_1 <- c("paracetamol", "aspirin", NA, NA, NA)
    drug_2 <- c("ibuprofen", "ibuprofen", NA, "aspirin", NA)
    drug_3 <- c("aspirin", "paracetamol", "ibuprofen",NA, NA)
    drug_4 <- c("codine", NA, NA, NA, NA)
    drug_5 <- c("cough syrup", NA,NA, NA, NA)
    drug_6 <- c("cocodamol", NA,NA, NA, NA)
    
    patients_data <- data.frame(patient_id,dates, drug_1, drug_2, drug_3, drug_4, drug_5, drug_6);patients_data

  patient_id      dates      drug_1    drug_2      drug_3 drug_4      drug_5    drug_6
1          1 2023-01-01 paracetamol ibuprofen     aspirin codine cough syrup cocodamol
2          2 2022-01-01     aspirin ibuprofen paracetamol   <NA>        <NA>      <NA>
3          3 2019-01-01        <NA>      <NA>   ibuprofen   <NA>        <NA>      <NA>
4          3 2019-01-02        <NA>   aspirin        <NA>   <NA>        <NA>      <NA>
5          4 2019-01-02        <NA>      <NA>        <NA>   <NA>        <NA>      <NA>
```

Comment: Is it meaningful that (for instance) `ibuprofen` in row 3 is in `drug_3` and 1-2 are `NA`?

Comment: No, in my actual dataset, I used fuzzy string matching on each column. When there wasn't a sufficient enough match, an NA was imputed; in many cases, the rows look like this.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if the numbers of each drug are important, but you can try something like this.

```r
library(tidyverse)

patients_data %>%  
  pivot_longer(
    starts_with('drug')
  ) %>% 
  distinct(
    patient_id,
    dates,
    value
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    name = str_glue('drug_{row_number()}'),
    .by = c(patient_id, dates)
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = name,
    values_from = value
  )
#> # A tibble: 5 x 9
#>   patient_id dates      drug_1      drug_2    drug_3 drug_4 drug_5 drug_6 drug_7
#>        <dbl> <chr>      <chr>       <chr>     <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1          1 2023-01-01 paracetamol ibuprofen aspir~ <NA>   codine cough~ cocod~
#> 2          2 2022-01-01 aspirin     <NA>      ibupr~ parac~ <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
#> 3          3 2019-01-01 <NA>        ibuprofen <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
#> 4          3 2019-01-02 <NA>        asprin    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  
#> 5
```

Comment: Good point.  I appreciate the feedback :)  I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned in my question; I will be summing across rows, so number of drugs is important

Comment: I think `patient_id = 3` should have 2 rows because there are 2 separate dates.  I agree that `patient_id = 4` shouldn't be missing though.  It's because (s)he doesn't have any medications.  @Martin, if a patient doesn't have any medications, what is the expected output?

Comment: Yes, patient 3 should have two rows. I would like to keep the patients with all NAs for medications, but have them with only 1 row.

Comment: @Martin, edited to keep patients with no medications.  A side effect of that is the possibility of empty columns.

Comment: Thanks for this! It all looks good, just one more thing; patient 1 has asprin in twice, do you know how to get it so that only unique entries within patient and within date are retained?

Comment: @Martin, yes you can.  Edited above with a call to `distinct()`.